# How can I remove the “To do” sidebar in Evolution?

Tags: evolution

I recently switched from Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04. As a result I now have a sidebar “To do” in Evolution on the right-hand side of the e-mail view. How can I remove this sidebar?

Moving the ruler between the actual e-mail view and the “To do” sidebar doesn’t help: you can only make the sidebar very slim this way but cannot make it disappear completely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Evolution lets you toggle whether or not the “To do” bar is shown:

**View** → **Layout** → **Show To Do Bar**